# GPA Calculator for python and adding to a variable in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables

I have to make a GPA Calculator for my class. It has to take number grades and convert them to our school's scale. It also has to determine if the class is AP or Honors. AP adds +1 the weight and Honors add +.5 to the weight. Our scale is simple if the class is CP or Career which is just F=0 D=1 C=2 B=3 A=4. I know the final GPA isnt calculated right yet but I cant figure out how to add points the variable `points` when the grade is input. What am I doing wrong?

```
apClass= int(input('How many AP classes are you taking?'))
honClass= int(input('\nHow many Honors classes are you taking?'))
g1=int(input('\nWhat is your first grade?'))
g2=int(input('\nWhat is your second grade?'))
g3=int(input('\nWhat is your third grade?'))
g4=int(input('\nWhat is your fourth grade?'))
points=(apClass*1)+(honClass*.5)

def GetGrades (g1,g2,g3,g4):
    if [g1,g2,g3,g4] < 90:
        points += 4.0
    elif [g1,g2,g3,g4] >90>80:
        points += 3.0
    elif [g1,g2,g3,g4] >70>80:
        points += 2.0
    elif [g1,g2,g3,g4] >60>70:
        points += 1.0
    elif [g1,g2,g3,g4] < 60:
        points += 0.0
    else:
        return('invalid grade')

print (points)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Be specific on what you're looking for and what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Adding to a value isn't your problem; it's the conditions in your if/elif statements that are broken.

Comment: @IanHank what does it mean that list is smaller than integer?

Comment: Additionally to what was said: if AP weighs `+1` or 100% more than usual, i.e. 200%, you would have to calculate `apClass * 2`; the same for Honors: `honClass * 1.5`. This might be part of your problem.

Comment: you probably mean `sum([g1,g2,g3,g4])` and `90>80` always returns `True`.

Comment: I guess what i am trying to ask is when I input their grades I need to convert them to the GPA scale  and add them to the total points. If the student inputs a 95 i need it to convert to a 4 and add the 4 to the total points.

Comment: @IanHank Is a 90 a 4 or a 3?

Comment: A 90% is a 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is my solution to the question:

```
class CalcGPA:

def __init__(self):
    self.g1 = float(input("Please enter grade 1: "))
    self.g2 = float(input("Please enter grade 2: "))
    self.g3 = float(input("Please enter grade 3: "))
    self.g4 = float(input("Please enter grade 4: "))
    self.ap = float(input("Please enter total AP classes: "))
    self.hn = float(input("Please enter total Honors classes: "))
    self.weight = self.ap + (self.hn * 0.5)
    self.grades_list = [self.g1, self.g2, self.g3, self.g4]
    self.gpa_list = []
    self.gpa = 0

def conv_grades(self):
    for i in self.grades_list:
        if i >= 90:
            self.gpa_list.append(4)
        elif 80 <= i <= 89:
            self.gpa_list.append(3)
        elif 70 <= i <= 79:
            self.gpa_list.append(2)
        elif 60 <= i <= 69:
            self.gpa_list.append(1)
        else:
            self.gpa_list.append(0)
    self.gpa = (sum(self.gpa_list) + self.weight) / len(self.gpa_list)

def show_gpa(self):
    print("Your current GPA as calculated is: {}".format(self.gpa))
```

Lets break it down so you understand whats going on here and can gleam why you are having some issues. Firstly, we are doing this as Object Oriented Programming because I assume you will have multiple objects (I.E. students needing to calculate their grades). This allows you to encapsulate the data into a reusable structure. While I'm sure my version could be greatly improved, this is what I whipped up in 10 mins. So at first we define our class, and then define init. This initializes our beginning prompts and variables needed to run the program you are trying to create.

As you can see, I have 4 grades, ap classes and hn classes taken and stored as floats. Now this is where you weren't too clear on things. The weight that these classes add to the overall GPA is 1 for AP and 0.5 for Honors(hn). So if it is 1 point for AP I see no reason to multiply anything really as its already a whole number. With the 0.5 adding into the mix, we would multiply by 0.5 so we get half a point or each class that was honors. Add these two numbers together and you get your final weight that these classes will affect our gpa at the end.

I then stored the grades that were given to us in a simple list to be iterated through later. I initialized an empty list for our gpa values that we are going to calculate as well as setting our final gpa to 0 for now.

Next we define our first method as conv_grades(). As you can see, we use a simple for loop to iterate through our list at each item location in that list. Then we use If Elif statements to return the values we need to properly calculate our gpa values. This appends the values, each time the loop is run into the gpa_list we created under the initialization.

From here it is simple math to calculate a gpa. Now you werent too clear on this part either, but im assuming here that you will want to sum your gpa values up and divide them by the total number of classes/grades submitted. I.E. get the avg of your gpa scores to calculate a real gpa. To do this, we take the sum of the gpa_list and then add the weight to it. After that, we divide by the len() of the list so its scalable in the future if you want to have larger lists of grades (though of course you will need to change your code some to allow for more inputs from users than what is statically available now.) By doing this we return our gpa value.

At this point you could simply just print it out, but I decided for fun to just make another method to print out our gpa. This is the show_gpa() method at the bottom.

Now if you are unfamiliar with how to run code like this as it is not linear, you will need to import it into your python interpreter.

```
import "whatever you named this file(for demo im calling this gpa.py"
```

Now to create an instance(object) we call:

```
student_1 = gpa.CalcGPA() # Notice the gpa first, this denotes the filename we just imported
```

By doing this, it will start to ask you for all the variables we setup under the **init**() function. Enter those in.

Now at this point we have our object created, and our number plugged in. to calculate the gpa simply type:

```
student_1.conv_grades()
```

This will not output anything to your screen though, to show the gpa simply type out:

```
student_1.show_gpa()
```

That's it! Now hopefully this shows you how I at least would have gone about doing it, and hopefully you can see where you went wrong in your code outside of what others have already told you. Hope this helps you some.

P.S. With a program that accepts user input, you will want some kind of error handling and checking to make sure they are not trying input illegal characters. I think that is outside the scope of whats being asked of you, but I just wanted to point that out so I don't get flamed for it.

Comment: Your welcome! Dont forget to mark the answer with the star if it answered your question :) If you need any more help with it, just let me know.

Comment: Actually, it is saying that its expecting indents on the init and the first self.g1 line. Once i indent those it wont ask what the first grade is and tells me there is no "self" variable and gives another error.

Comment: one second, let me look at something

Comment: https://youtu.be/1IxPPFIUYWU Here watch the video I just recorded to show the proper indentation along with how to run the program

Comment: that link is taking me to my own youtube channel to edit my videos try a different link thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9llzfsqsm8e4uy/gpa.py?dl=0 you can download the file from my dropbox as well from this link